# Skip over function error and continue with next check (VLOOKUP)

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a basic VLOOKUP to get an employees email address.

However, when the lookup value enters an employees name that doesn't exist in the array, it throws an error.

I added an "On Error Resume Next" but this just caused the remainder of the email addresses to be the last email address encountered, instead of continuing the search and using the current employee as the search variable.

What I want is when the search variable `ProjectManName` doesn't exist in the array, to just skip over that line, and continue the search as normal. I will then go and fill in the empty email addresses manually.

```
Dim myLookupValue As Range
Dim strResult As String
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLoop As Long
Dim ProjectManName As String

Set myLookupValue = Worksheets("Employees").Range("A1", Worksheets("Employees").Range("B1").End(xlDown))

With Worksheets("Project Summary")

    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For lngLoop = 2 To lngLastRow
        On Error Resume Next
       ProjectManName = .Cells(lngLoop, 1).Value
       strResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProjectManName, myLookupValue, 2, False)
       Range("K" & lngLoop).Value = strResult
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next

End With
```

Also, for the myLookupValue, do I need the second instance of Worksheets("Employees")? When I didn't do this it also gave an error because the second cell in the range looked at the current worksheet instead of the Employees worksheet.

Lastly, how can I replace "K" in `Range("K" & lngLoop).Value` to be the first empty column?

Comment: Remove the `.WorksheetFunction` part and it will allow the pass through.

Comment: You will want to find the last column so that you can replace "K" in your range.  I would recommend using `Cells()` rather than `Range()` since you can use the number as is from `lc = sheets("project summary").cells(1, sheets("project summary").columns.count).end(xltoleft).column`, where `1` in cells is the first row (typically headers) and "lc" stands for last column.  the cells reference would be `Cells(ingLoop, lc)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I did as you mentioned but still got _Run-time error '13': Type mismatch_

Comment: See Mathieu's answer below, he tells you why and how to fix

Answer (score 4):

> *when the lookup value enters an employees name that doesn't exist in the array, it throws an error.*

That's entirely by design. `Application.WorksheetFunction` functions are early-bound and *raise* errors instead of *returning* them, which is completely idiomatic VB behavior.

Looks like you want the "Excel worksheet" behavior, where a worksheet function that errors out will *return* a `Variant/Error` value that the cell displays as `#N/A`: that `Variant/Error` value makes `IsError` return `True`, and can only be legally compared to other error values, e.g. `CVErr(xlErrNa)`.

Like many COM types, the `Excel.Application` interface is *extensible*, meaning members can be added to it at run-time. Turns out, it's effectively extended with members of the `WorksheetFunction` interface, so `Application.VLookup` not only compiles perfectly fine (as does `Application.AnythingWhatsoever`), it's a late-bound implementation that behaves exactly like the worksheet function does when invoked by a worksheet cell: it *returns* a `Variant/Error` value rather than *raising* a standard, idiomatic run-time error... assuming you get all the parameters right (late-bound calls don't get *IntelliSense*/autocomplete), because if you make a typo (`Option Explicit` can't save you) or get the parameters wrong, expect error 438 or 1004 to be raised.

But you can't capture the return value in a `String` - that'll be a *type mismatch* error when the lookup yields an `Error` value (you can't coerce that type into anything other than a `Variant`).

```
Dim lookupResult As Variant
lookupResult = Application.VLookup(ProjectManName, myLookupValue, 2, False)
If Not IsError(lookupResult) Then
    strResult = CStr(lookupResult)
    '...
''Else
''    'lookup failed
End If
```

That said the early-bound version should generally be preferred, be it only for *IntelliSense*. `On Error Resume Next` *used correctly* can be helpful here - simply pull the lookup into its own scope:

```
For lngLoop = 2 To lngLastRow
    ProjectManName = .Cells(lngLoop, 1).Value
    [ActiveSheet.]Range("K" & lngLoop).Value = GetProjectManager(ProjectManName)
    'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select '<~ why?
Next
```

```
Private Function GetProjectManager(ByVal name As String) As String
     Dim source As Range
     With Worksheets("Employees")
         On Error Resume Next
         GetProjectManager = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown)), 2, False)
         On Error GoTo 0
     End With
End Function
```

As for `myLookupValue` (bad name: should be `myLookupRange` or `lookupSource` or `lookupTable` - "lookup value" is generally understood/read as being the value you're looking for) - you *absolutely do* need a *reference* to the `Employees` sheet (unqualified `Range` calls are a very good recipe for error 1004) - that doesn't mean you need to dereference that object from the `Worksheets` collection twice - as shown above... note that by moving the lookup into its own scope, we also remove the need for the caller to even need to care about the lookup source table.

Comment: I had never seen the term *idiomatic* used outside of music (e.g., Bach's music, typically, is idiomatic of the Baroque period), so had to look that up in context... learned something new today!

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon I tried both ways and couldn't get either to work. However, I realized while running through it that I had defined the problem incorrectly regarding the missing ProjectManName. I figured it out a different way. But I'm glad you showed me a different method I can use in the future. And also a great explanation on error's. Thanks for the heads up regarding naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment as answer to be easier to read.  Only answers the last question in the multi-question post.

---

You will want to find the last column so that you can replace "K" in your range. I would recommend using Cells() rather than Range() since you can use the number as is from:

```
dim lc as long
lc = sheets("project summary").cells(1, sheets("project summary").columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
```

where "1" in cells is the first row (typically headers) and "lc" stands for last column. The cells reference would be `Cells(ingLoop, lc)`, given your example.

Comment: Thanks, Cyril. That worked perfectly. Just one question.

How come we use .End(xlToLeft) instead of xlToRight when I'm working with the last column on the right? I can't see how it picks up the last column on the right with using xlToLeft.

Comment: @eyeScream the `.columns.count` will position at the maximum column (which is ~16,000) and then from there position itself to the left, equivalen tto send keys for ctrl + left.  That will indicate the last column with data, for the given row (in this case, 1).

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense. Thank you.