# INDEX MATCH across multiple columns for a large data set

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting some automation to combine 2 databases in Excel. Each row has a unique identifier (column C). I have written some code that works but it is clunky and ugly and not adaptable to much larger problems.

Currently the code loops through the rows in the destination sheets and matches were it finds a result. If there is no result, it uses the errorskip to go to the next column. It works but I would like to be able to move lots of columns around and adding another repeat line and errorhandler in for each column is not good.

Any tips would be appreciated to similify the code in the DO While loop

```
Public Sub HistoryTransfer()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'copies last month's history information into this months RAG spreadsheet
    Dim HistoryWS As Worksheet
    Set HistoryWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAG History")

    Dim RAGspreadsheet As Worksheet
    Set RAGspreadsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAG Spreadsheet")

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = HistoryWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim RAGlastRow As Integer
    RAGlastRow = RAGspreadsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 11
    Do While i < RAGlastRow
        On Error GoTo Errorhandler
        RAGspreadsheet.Range("Z" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Index(HistoryWS.Range("N11", "N" & lastRow), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
Errorskip:
        On Error GoTo Errorhandler2
        RAGspreadsheet.Range("AA" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Index(HistoryWS.Range("O11", "O" & lastRow), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
Errorskip2:
        On Error GoTo Errorhandler3
        RAGspreadsheet.Range("AB" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Index(HistoryWS.Range("P11", "P" & lastRow), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
Errorskip3:
        i = i + 1
    Loop

Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
    Resume Errorskip:

Errorhandler2:
    Resume Errorskip2:

Errorhandler3:
    Resume Errorskip3:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `WorkSheetFunction.` with `Application.` to trap the error.  Additionally, you can avoid the worksheet functions altogether using `Find`, looping through your columns.

Comment: @Cyril thats interesting. Why does using `application.` not need the error handlers? It works great, thank you but slightly confused.

Comment: @AlexH [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383812/1188513) should shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: Added it into my answer, but will rehash here that `application.worksheetfunction` or `worksheetfunction` will return a result and if the result is an error, it stops the code to correct the issue; for `application.` the error is the value and does not cause a stop, e.g., assigning error code as the value of the variable

Comment: @MathieuGuindon threw your link in my answer as you explained it exceptionally better than my ELI5 response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using find, described in comment to the post (untested):

```
arr = array("26", "27", "28") 'Z, AA, AB
For i = 11 to RAGlastrow
    Set rng = HistoryWS.Columns(3).Find(RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i,3).Value, lookin:=xlValues)
    If NOT rng = Nothing then
        For j = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
            RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i,arr(j)) = HistoryWS.Cells(rng.Row,arr(j)-12)
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```

---

Will also re-state the first sentence of the comment:

```
Replace `WorkSheetFunction.` with `Application.` to trap the error.
```

This happens due to the behaviour of each.  `WorksheetFunction` treats the error as an error and stops the code, jumping to debug mode.  For `Application.`, VBA will assign the error as the variable and move on to the next.

---

**Edit1:** Mat's Mug did a better explanation the other day about the difference for `WorkSheetFunction` versus `Application` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383812/1188513 (copied link from his comment)